# rake aborted! " uninitialized constant MysqlCompat::MysqlRes "

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> Pranay-Tares-MacBook-Pro:music_library pranaytare$ rake db:migrate
>   (in /Users/pranaytare/Sites/music_library)
>
> rake aborted!
>
> uninitialized constant MysqlCompat::MysqlRes

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling gem with arch flags:
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config